# Using a truth table, is the sentence below a tautology, contradiction or contingency?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

(P ⇒ Q) ⇔ (¬P ∨ Q)

Also, I am not sure what the double headed arrow is supposed to mean. I know a single headed arrow means "implies" but I am not sure about the double headed one.

Comment: The double headed arrow is a biconditional. The statement is true if and only if P and Q are both 1 or both 0. It's the same has having (P implies Q) and (Q implies P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we setup a truth table:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    P & Q & \mathbf{P \rightarrow Q} & \mathbf{\neg P \vee Q} \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1}\\ \hline
    0 & 1 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1}\\ \hline
    1 & 0 & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}\\ \hline
    1 & 1 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1}\\ \hline
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    P \rightarrow Q & \neg P \vee Q & \mathbf{(P \rightarrow Q) \leftrightarrow (\neg P \vee Q)} \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & \mathbf{1} \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & \mathbf{1}\\ \hline
    0 & 0 & \mathbf{1}\\ \hline
    1 & 1 & \mathbf{1}\\ \hline
\end{array}$

Your expression gives nothing but $1$, so therefore it's a tautology.